# In industrially produced soup, how does each can contain equal parts of all ingredients?

Tags: soup, canning, food-processing

In the soup that you get at the store, how come you never get cans of just broth?

You'd think that if the soup were made in a large vat, the first few cans would have very little broth and the last few cans would have exclusively broth... but that's obviously not the case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Obviously, every manufacturer is going to have their own proprietary methods.

However, canned goods are often made by combining ingredients (possibly partially cooked) directly into the cans, and then pressure cooking them *in the can* as part of the canning process.

So, for example, the broth, some celery, and some carrots might be added to the open can in measured amounts.  Then, the can is sealed, and pressure cooked to both sterilize the contents, and to cook the celery and carrots through.